# How to keep only red text on this image?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I need to keep only red text from images like this one.

[Image with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbGaf.jpg)

I have tried turning all pixels with less than 210-240 value for red in RGB to black, but it depends much on the image and the light of it, so it is not a good solution and is not always working.

I would need to make it using Python.

Comment: You need to check the values in the red channel but also in the green channel.

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you! So simple but I hadn't thought of it.